Differences between clang versions on windows
I've heard about clang-cl as a "microsoft-flavoured" version of clang but looking at my configuration I'm observing the following:

I've got an executable clang in my msys2 directories
I've got an executable clang-cl in my msys2 directories
I've got an executable clang in my visual-studio build tools directories
I've got an executable clang-cl in my visual-studio build tools directories

What are the differences between these versions?
(Ultimately I'd like to see if it's worth the effort to add support for clang-cl in my compilation framework)

Additional data:
Calling each of them with -v gives me Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu for the first one and Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc for all the others.

MSVC compatibility "When Clang compiles C++ code for Windows, it attempts to be compatible with MSVC. There are multiple dimensions to compatibility.  First, Clang attempts to be ABI-compatible, ..."

clang[++] vs clang-cl normally only affects the style of command-line arguments. clang[++] is GCC-like and is the primary interface. clang-cl is MSVC-like (MSVC = cl.exe).
Apparently in MSYS2 Clang it also switches it from MinGW-compatible mode to MSVC-compatible (see --target below).
You can use both clang[++] and clang-cl to compile MSVC-compatible programs. (Though the former requires knowing what flags to pass, which aren't obvious.) I doubt it makes sense to use clang-cl to compile non-MSVC-comatible programs (such as MinGW-compatible or not for Windows at all).
The official build of Clang vs MSYS2 Clang affects the default --target=... (using MSVC ABI and libraries vs MinGW ABI and libraries). This can be seen in clang --version.
Clang installed by Visual Studio, like the one from Clang's official installer, uses MSVC-compatible --target by default. I don't know if there's any difference between them.


if it's worth the effort to add support for clang-cl in my compilation framework

If you support MSVC (cl.exe), then supporting clang-cl is trivial, because the flags are (mostly?) the same.

just to be sure, and seeing the output of -v, allow me to rephrase: it means that only the first one uses a GNU ABI while the 3 others or MSVC compatible by default (at least while I don't set the -target options)? The -cl version uses cl options while the other uses the gcc-like ones?

And, will I get different diagnoses using the MSVC-ABI-compliant wrt to the GNU-ABI one?

@Oersted "first one uses a GNU ABI while the 3 others or MSVC compatible". Yeah. I've realized I missed this part of the question, edited the answer. "The -cl version uses cl options while the other uses the gcc-like ones?" Yeah. "And, will I get different diagnoses" You mean style of diagnostics, as in error/warning messages?

Regarding diagnoses, I'm always compiling with cl, gcc (msys2) and clang (msys2) on windows; gcc and clang on linux, which might gives different warnings. So yes, will clang for MSVC-ABI give different error/warning than cl and clang for GNU ABI?

@Oersted There's a small chance of it because of different standard libraries, but other than that no, they should be the same.
